# redirect output to text file after user input

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I have created a JNDI java program that gives different kind of output as user specification. For example user can run the program with different parameters as :

```
java MyProg -o row -u username -l uId1,uId2,....
```

here user can specify options as :
-o : for output format(row basis/column basis)
-u : connect to server with different user(then program will ask for password)
-l : program will show output for given user id(s)

Now the thing is for every option I have define a default value(configuration) so its up to user if he want to change the configuration then he will specify the option. So user can call the program as:

```
java MyProg
java Myprog -o col
java MyProg -u username 
java MyProg -l uId1,uId2,...
java MyProg -l uId1,uId2,... -o col
```

and so on..

so whenever user use -u(for changing the username) then the program will ask the password after that it shows the result.

Now I want to provide a facility that user can redirect the console output to a text file but when I am trying "java MyProg > filename.txt" then its not working.

Please tell me how to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Don't you print your results to stdout normally?

Comment: Its showing result to stdout but I want to provide facility to user that he can redirect the result to a file(optional).

Comment: Well, if shell redirections are not working, it seems like the results do not go to stdout (you say yourself that `java MyProg > filename.txt` does not redirect anything)

Comment: oh sorry..Its redirecting the output but when I write java MyProg -u username > filename.txt then its showing error

Comment: OK, so the fact that there is an error there has nothing to do with your first problem then?

Comment: I think the problem is occurring coz of option facility

Comment: OK, see my answer. However, this answer will not work if your _native code_ also prints to stdout.

Comment: "java MyProg -u username > filename.txt" will be useless if you are expecting an input from the user. Try to implement writing the output to file as an option or default behavior and handle the same in the code as fge has given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` is a [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (which is why you can use such methods as `println()` etc on it).

What you can do is, if you see the option to redirect to a file, just create a new `PrintStream` to the destination file:

```
PrintStream stdout = System.out;

// outfile is a String
if (outfile != null)
    stdout = new PrintStream(outfile);
```

And use `stdout` instead of `System.out` to output results.

Comment: Instead System.setOut() can be used, so that System.out.println() also will be written to the specified file.